# Vaadin anchor - catch deafult click event

Tags: java, vaadin, anchor, vaadin14

I am new to Vaadin framework and I was wondering if there is a way of catching the deafult click event of an Anchor? (Vaadin14, Java only - v11)

I know i can do this:

```
Anchor download = new Anchor()
download.getElement().addEventListener("click", event -> doStuff())
```

but it does not seem to be the deafult built in click listener as i am able to add an anchor with a StreamResource.
Then, clicking the Anchor starts the file download - without adding any additional listeners.

Answer to any of these question would solve my problem i believe:

- Is there a way of catching this anchor click event?
- Is there a way of triggerring it programatically in the code like the Button click() method?
- What kind of @DomEvent is this if it is a @DomEvent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you actually using the anchor as a link or as a button? If the latter, you could just use a Button and style it as a link.

---

Answer to your questions:

1. the way you did, `addEventListener("click", e ->`
2. `download.getElement().callFunction("click")` ([the same as `clickInClient`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-button-flow/blob/69118a1461bac856cff76ed579de9cc0c6ea7fd0/vaadin-button-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/button/Button.java#L267))
3. I don't think it matters for you. All you need is to react to the event and if you need some data, you can [use `addEventData()`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.6.7/com/vaadin/flow/dom/DomListenerRegistration.html#addEventData-java.lang.String-)

---

You could alternatively try to subclass `Anchor` implementing the [`ClickNotifier` mixin interface](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/2cb3acb4a9822a8ea2fc827069576c9367061260/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/ClickNotifier.java#L41) which would provide you with the `addClickListener()` method, also you could then fire this `ClickEvent` manually, as is done in [button's `click()`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-button-flow/blob/69118a1461bac856cff76ed579de9cc0c6ea7fd0/vaadin-button-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/button/Button.java#L257)

```java
public class ClickableAnchor extends Anchor implements ClickNotifier {
    public void click() {
        fireEvent(new ClickEvent<>(this, false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false,
                false, false));
    }

    public void clickInClient() {
        getElement().callJsFunction("click");
    }
}
```